# Effective way to run an exe file using Visual Basic 6?

Tags: vb6

I have a sample C# console application which consists of an .exe file. I need to open this file using Visual Basic 6 in order to pass parameters. How can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vb6: how to run a program from vb6 and close it once it finishes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228410/vb6-how-to-run-a-program-from-vb6-and-close-it-once-it-finishes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the VBA `Shell` command.

Example:

```
Shell """C:\Program Files\CSharpProgram\CSharpProgram.exe"" Parameter1 Parameter Second"
```

Double "double quotes" inside "double quotes" translate to single "double quotes" in VBA/VB6. Helps if you need to use paths with spaces.

The shell command is asynchronous by default.

Check out the Shell function reference at Microsoft Website:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278437(v=office.15).aspx